# Set up an Alerts on power BI dashboard through the portal

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, power-bi-report-server

Do power BI supports the alerts facility for end users?
We have embedded reports on our portal and from there our individual customers are getting insights. Now few of them requesting an alert for their items when it reaches to certain quantity. I am aware of dashboard alerts but not sure how would it work for embedded reports. Power BI services offer alert facility for dashboards but how can one individual set up the same alerts from the portal instead of power BI service. Or should we use different approach to set up an alert?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is a major limitation of power bi embedded. You likely need to build a custom function outside of power bi to accomplish this

Comment: Thank you Derek, what do you mean by build a custom function outside of power BI?